# Join two tables with adding new column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables like

```
-----Permission Table-------|----RolePermission Table------
PermissionId    MenuName    | RoleId PemissionID
1                Home       |    1       1  
2                Incoming   |    2       1
3                Sent       |    1       3
```

My query is like this

```
Select Permission.PermissionId, Permission.MenuName, RolePermission.RoleId,
case 
when 
Permission.PermissionId=RolePermission.PermissionId and RolePermission.RoleId=2 then 1
else 0 
end as IsAssignedRole
from Permission , RolePermission
```

I want output like this

```
PermissionId    MenuName    RoleId  IsAssignedRole
1               Home           2         1
2               Incoming       2         0
3               Sent           2         0
```

Basically i want to fetch all permission menuname which binded to my checkbox and check if permissionID is assigned to role so i can set checked that same checkbox. If i pass null it should return me the

```
PermissionId    MenuName    RoleId  IsAssignedRole
1               Home          Null       0
2               Incoming      Null       0
3               Sent          Null       0
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Never use implicit joins. What you currently have is a cross join. It may or may not be what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `left join`.  I think this does what you want:

```
Select p.PermissionId, p.MenuName, rp.RoleId,
       (case when rp.PermissionId is not null then 1 else 0 end) as IsAssignedRole
from Permission p left join
     RolePermission rp
     on rp.PermissionId = p.PermissionId and rp.RoleId = 2 ;
```